# Marklogic Custom Replacement Constructors via Javascript

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to write a custom replacement constructor in marklogic via server side javascript?

So far I could only find examples/documentation that only uses XQuery: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/partial-update#id_80429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MarkLogic 8.0-7 / 9.0-2, it is not supported. I'll report that as a bug.